# Periodically import a large synonym database via DataImportHandler into Solr

Tags: solr, synonym

I have a large synonym-database in a relational DB with a simple layout:

`| word | group_id | changeDate |`

It is managed externally, i.e users can add, update or delete synonyms. Is it possible to import this data into a [managed schema](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/configuration-guide/managed-resources.html) using a DataImportHandler like done with search indexes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not possible, but you can update the managed schema locally and then upload it to your solr server with the help of zookeeper and keep the synonym.txt file updated.

you can refer this documentation for updating the configuration [here](https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/command-line-utilities.html)